# Pull Requests - Must fetch first?

Tags: git

I originally cloned down a project.  Should I have forked it first in order to do a pull request later?

If I did the following, will a pull request still be possible?

```
1) clone the project
3) create a local branch, switch to it
4) work on it, commit some changes to it
5) change back to the master branch (checkout)
6) -- what do I do here, merge changes?  How does a pull request work?
```

Comment: im pretty sure you have to fork in order to make a PR back into the original project.

Comment: I was told you just need to push your branch back to master

Comment: while in the master branch I did a git push -u origin [branch name] and I get "Branch update-readme set up to track remote branch update-readme-filesizelimit from origin.
"

Comment: Git itself has no notion of "fork" or "pull request". Is this question about GitHub?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do a PR from the same project (that you own, meaning you can push you branch back to that upstream repo), then no, you don't need a fork.

You can [make a PR from any branch of your repo](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/).

> Create a pull request to propose and collaborate on changes to a repository. These changes are proposed in a branch, which ensures that the master branch only contains finished and approved work.

[image: https://help.github.com/assets/images/help/pull_requests/pull-request-review-edit-branch.png]

You can compare changes within the same repo or, as mentioned in the picture above, across forks. In your case, you don't have a fork.

You don't merge to master locally: you push your branch, compare it to master on GitHub and create your PR there.